# What kind of technology is needed to implement parental lock kind of application?

Tags: java, php, vbscript, parental-control

What technology is required to create parental lock application that prevents children to view inappropriate sites over the Internet?I'm thinking of creating this as my final year engineering project and I'm good at Java and PHP. I thought of creating few websites using PHP, a DNS server using Java and somehow block websites using connection between Java and PHP. But if there is any other way or technology present that could ease my work then please tell me.Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: There's a lot of ways to implement parental controls that have varying levels of difficulty and effectiveness. For example, it would be relatively easy to create a proxy server that all internet traffic passes through, but it is also relatively easy to disable proxy usage if you haven't locked down the OS settings. I think the professional software (Net Nanny, etc) hooks into certain parts of the Windows operating system that control networking, but I don't know.

Comment: I made a vbscript that use Norton ConnectSafe service; so if you like to test it, just edit your post and add the tag vbscript, and i will share you this script.

Comment: Ok..@Hackoo ..Just for the sake of idea! Thanks!

Comment: @PranayBinju I can't reply for the moment since your question is on hold; so i recomand you to ask another question with tag vbscript and the title "How we can use OpenDNS and Norton ConnectSave services to change DNS with Vbscript ?" I will reply to you immediately !

Comment: Why don't you have a look at products which already do this and investigate how they work.  The main problem is having an extensive list of sites to block, so you are better off using an existing product.

Comment: @PranayBinju Try this vbscript ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596280/vbscript-to-change-dns-server?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @PranayBinju And this Vbscript is used for Norton ConnectSave Service ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596280/vbscript-to-change-dns-server?answertab=active#tab-top